# RabbitMQ Expired TTL Message don't get into Dead Letter Exchange

Tags: rabbitmq

i want to achieve that a message can only be consumed in 60 seconds. That way i have two Queues:

#### worker

Gets consumed but never directly published.

Arguments:

- durable:  true

Bound to exchange `worker` (type = direct).

#### scheduler

Gets published but never consumed.

Arguments:

- x-dead-letter-exchange:   worker
- x-message-ttl:    2000
- durable:  true

Bound to exchange `scheduler` (type = direct).

---

When i send a message to `scheduler` it appears for 2 seconds, then disappears - as expected.

What i would expect next, is, that the message pops up in the `worker` queue, but isn't appearing.

I'm not binding a routing key or anything else.

Question: Why don't expired messages get re-published in the dead letter exchange?

Comment: you need a routing key i guess.. i am not sure how to make it work without it in place.

Answer (score 1):

Dead-Letter Exchange is an exchange, you need to bind the worker queue to the DLX with a suitable policy for the messages that are dead-lettered to land in the worker queue.